# Quedarme con palabras con 4 o más vocales

Tags: java

Tengo un problema a la hora de realizar este método, ya que no encuentro la manera de descartar las palabras que no cumplen mi condición.

Por ejemplo, si le paso un texto tal que así: "murcielago buenos dias que tal" 
debería devolver una lista con la palabra "murcielago" y descartar el resto, por no contener 4 vocales distintas.

Lo que tengo hecho es lo siguiente:

```
/**
 * Cuatro_Vocales.java
 * Escribe un método llamado palabrasCuatroVocales()que recibe una cadena de texto como parámetro 
 * y devuelve la lista de palabras con al menos cuatro vocales diferentes
 */


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class Cuatro_Vocales {

public static void palabrasCuatroVocales(String texto){

    texto = texto.toLowerCase();
    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

    int i, j;
    int ca, ce, ci, co, cu;
    int vocales = 0;
    String palabra = "";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(texto);
    System.out.println();


    ca = 0;
    ce = 0;
    ci = 0;
    co = 0;
    cu = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++){
        // charAt(i) devuelve el caracter de la posicion i 
        palabra+=texto.charAt(i);


        for (j = 0; j < palabra.length(); j++){
            if(palabra.charAt(j) == 'a') {
                ca++;
                  if(ca>1){
                        ca=1;
                    }
            }
            if(palabra.charAt(j) == 'e') {
                ce++;
                  if(ce>1){
                        ce=1;
                    }
            }
            if(palabra.charAt(j) == 'i') {
                ci++;
                  if(ci>1){
                        ci=1;
                    }
            }
            if(palabra.charAt(j) == 'o') {
                co++;
                  if(co>1){
                        co=1;
                    }
            }
            if(palabra.charAt(j) == 'u') {
                cu++;
                  if(cu>1){
                        cu=1;
                    }
                }
            }

        vocales = ca + ce + ci + co + cu;
        if (vocales >= 4) {

            lista.add(palabra);
            // Aqui esta el problema

            }
        }

    System.out.println(st.countTokens() + " Palabras");
    System.out.println();
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) System.out.println(st.nextToken());

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Palabras que cumplen la condicion: ");

    System.out.println(lista);

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    palabrasCuatroVocales("murcielago buenos dias que tal");

}
```

}

Me devuelve esto como resultado:

```
5 Palabras
murcielago
buenos
dias
que
tal

Palabras que cumplen la condicion: 
[murciela, murcielag, murcielago, murcielago , murcielago b, murcielago     bu, murcielago bue, murcielago buen, murcielago bueno, murcielago buenos,     murcielago buenos , murcielago buenos d, murcielago buenos di, murcielago     buenos dia, murcielago buenos dias, murcielago buenos dias , murcielago buenos     dias q, murcielago buenos dias qu, murcielago buenos dias que, murcielago     buenos dias que , murcielago buenos dias que t, murcielago buenos dias que ta,      murcielago buenos dias que tal]
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías descomponer el texto por espacios y luego, tras comprobar si cada palabra tiene las vocales, pasarlas a una lista:

```
string[] palabra = texto.split(" ");
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0; i<palabra.length; i++)
{
    if(palabra[i].contains("a") && palabra[i].contains("e") && palabra[i].contains("i") && palabra[i].contains("o"))
        lista.add(palabra[i]);
    else if(palabra[i].contains("a") && palabra[i].contains("e") && palabra[i].contains("i") && palabra[i].contains("u"))
        lista.add(palabra[i]);
    else if(palabra[i].contains("a") && palabra[i].contains("i") && palabra[i].contains("o") && palabra[i].contains("u"))
        lista.add(palabra[i]);
    else if(palabra[i].contains("e") && palabra[i].contains("i") && palabra[i].contains("o") && palabra[i].contains("u"))
        lista.add(palabra[i]);
}
```

En lista tienes almacenadas las palabras que tienen al menos 4 vocales distintas.

Estoy seguro que se puede hacer con un regex en unao dos líneas pero personalmente no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Si tuvieras que añadir tildes y diéresis sería un martirio

Comment: Tienes razón. Se podría utilizar la función Normalizer.normalize(texto, Normalizer.Form.NFD); para eliminar las tildes y diéresis. También te digo que he puesto esta propuesta porque no utilizo regex, lo cual veo que sería más efectivo y limpio en código, mejor solución.

Comment: Es cierto que es sencillo eliminar los diacríticos, pero en la discusión de usar/no regex, sería eso sumado a eliminar todos los caracteres que no son letras. Sigue siendo sencillo, pero agrega bastantes líneas de código.

Answer (score 3):

La manera más facil que se me ocurre es:

- Separar la frase en palabras
- En cada palabra, usar una [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) para sacar todas las vocales
- Ir metiendo las vocales en un Set (estructura de datos donde no permite la repeticion de elementos)
- Y si el set tiene longitud 4 o más, entonces es una palabra valida, como "murcielago"

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String frase = "Buenos días, murciélago. ¿Qué tal? aeiou!";
        System.out.println(comprobar(frase));
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> comprobar (String frase){

        String [] palabras =  frase.split(" ");
        ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[aeiouáéíóúü]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        for (String palabra : palabras) {

            Matcher m = pat.matcher(palabra);
            Set<String> vocales = new HashSet<String>();
            while (m.find()) {
                vocales.add(m.group(0));

            }
            if(vocales.size() >=4){

                out.add(palabra.replaceAll("[,.:!;()]", ""));//quitar signos de puntuacion
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
>>> [murciélago, aeiou]
```

[Ejemplo online](https://www.ideone.com/ZG5ZDF)

Comment: En vez del `.replaceAll()` para eliminar signos de puntuación, podrías hacer `.split("[^a-záéíóúüñ]+")` en vez de sólo espacios al inicio. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

La siguiente expresión regular coincide con palabras con al menos 4 vocales: <sup><sup>[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5kXmDw/1)</sup></sup>

```
(?:[b-df-hj-nñp-tv-z]*[aeiouáéíóúü]){4}[a-záéíóúüñ]*
```

Descripción:

- `(?:[b-df-hj-nñp-tv-z]*[aeiouáéíóúü]){4}` ≝ Repetir esto 4 veces:

  - `[b-df-hj-nñp-tv-z]*` ≝ cualquier cantidad de consonantes
  - `[aeiouáéíóúü]` ≝ una vocal
- `[a-záéíóúüñ]*` ≝ seguida de cualquier cantidad de letras

**Código:**

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
String texto = "Murciélago, buenos días animalito. ¿Qué tal? ¿Vino con su familia?";
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

//Compilar la expresión regular
final String regex = "(?:[b-df-hj-nñp-tv-z]*[aeiouáéíóúü]){4}[a-záéíóúüñ]*";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

//Agregar todas las coincidencias del regex a la lista
while (matcher.find()) {
    lista.add(matcher.group());
}

//Imprimir la lista
System.out.println(lista);
```

**Resultado:**

```
[Murciélago, animalito, familia]
```

**Demo:** https://ideone.com/1651RG